# swaping sublists of a list in python

Tags: python, list, swap

I just started learing python and I'm trying figure out how I can swap two parts of a list. Lets say I have the list

```
list=["apple","orange","car","bob","jack","peach"]
```

I want to swap elements before "car" with elements after "bob" so the result will be

```
["jack","peach","car","bob","apple","orange"]
```

This is what I have tried but it's not working:

```
def swap(list)
  firstpart=list[:list.index("car")]
  secondpart=list[list.index("bob"):]
  middlepart=list[list.index("car"):list.index("bob")]
  secondpart+middlepart+firstpart
```

but it is not mutating the list and I don't want to use return

Comment: I don't see any `list = ` or equivalent, which would be required to make change to a list

Comment: there are no `{ }` in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reassign the merge result to the `lst`. Note that , in slicing, first index is inclusive, second is exclusive.

```
def swap(lst):
    firstpart=lst[:lst.index("car")]
    secondpart=lst[lst.index("bob")+1:]
    middlepart=lst[lst.index("car"):lst.index("bob")+1]
    return firstpart + middlepart + secondpart
```

Comment: but lst= does not mutate the list outside of the function

Comment: is there a way to do this without return? just by using ":"

Comment: What do you actually want? Do you want to print the swapped list inside the function ? To use the swapped list outside the function, you have to return it from the function. If you insist, I can suggest some nasty work, like make `lst` global and then just assign the merged list to `lst`.